# If any value in table is not null, show only this not null values. Else show only values with null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table.

```
id    field1    field2
1     1000      500
2     1001      500
3     1002      500
4     1003      500
5     1004      500
6     1005      500
7     1006      500
8     1004      (null)
9     1003      (null)
10    1002      (null)
```

How to make a mysql query:

if any field2 is not null, show all where field2 is not null (id from 1 to 7).

And if all field2 are null (table without id from 1 to 7), then display all field2 where field2 is null (id from 8 to 10).

Comment: Im confused.com ! Your going to need to reword you question I think ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id 
                   FROM tab 
                   WHERE field2 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1) 
AND field2 IS NULL
OR field2 IS NOT NULL
```

Just for clarification

OP is looking for a statement that

having this data

```
id    field1    field2
6     1005      500
7     1006      500
8     1004      (null)
9     1003      (null)
```

the result is

```
id    field1    field2
6     1005      500
7     1006      500
```

having this data

```
id    field1    field2
8     1004      (null)
9     1003      (null)
```

the result is

```
id    field1    field2
8     1004      (null)
9     1003      (null)
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you mean display the value of `field1` if the value of `field2` IS NULL

```
SELECT COALESCE(field2, field1) fieldValue
FROM   tableName
```

- [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve all records where `field2` is not `NULL` than use this

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field2 <> NULL;
```

If you want the reverse use this

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: `= NULL` will return empty, use `IS NULL` instead.

Comment: @JW. I actually had written IS NULL but later changed it back, was confused, thanks for clearing it for me ;)

Comment: I know. But how "automatize" it? 

When any value field2 <> NULL then SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field2 <> NULL, 

but when all value field2 IS NULL then SELECT id FROM table_name [WHERE field2 IS NULL] - All in all this where is unnecessary, because if all they field2 is null to retrieve all of them

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT t.id,t.field1,t.field2
FROM t
WHERE id in (select id from t where field2 is not null)
or (select sum(ifnull(field2,0)) from t)=0
```

In case there at least 1 non null field 2 it will return rows where field2 isn't null.
In case all field2 are null it will return all rows.

Not sure if that is what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

How abouth this. **Note:** this is `tsql` >>  `@@rowcount`

```
--If `Any NOT null` you want to select `NOT null`
Select id,field1,field2 From T1 Where field2 IS NOT null

if (@@rowcount =0) --If `All null` you want to select `null`
    Select id,field1,field2 From T1 -- no need for Where field2 IS null
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like that

```
DECLARE @NullFields int;
set @NullFields=0;
select @NullFields= count(*) from tab Where field2 IS NOT NULL
if @NullFields == 0
    SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field2 <> NULL;
else
    SELECT id FROM table_name;
```

If all fields2 are null then we select all.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you have found a working solution already, but I also like this approach:

```
SELECT your_table.*
FROM your_table
WHERE
  field2 is not null =
  exists (select null from your_table where field2 is not null)
```

`Exists (...)` returns true if there's at least one record where `field2` is not null.
So if such record exists, take all rows where `field2 is not null = true` which means take all records where `field2` is not null.

If such record does not exists, take all rows where `field2 is not null = false` which means take all records where `field2` is null.